# What's the benefit of using a Result?

Tags: rust

I don't understand why `Result` exists in Rust. I can see how `Option` can be useful, but using `Result` just seems to complicate code unnecessarily.

Consider the following example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MyErr {
    None,
    FailOne,
}

fn returns_tuple() -> (u8, MyErr) {
    // (1, None) // <-- Success path
    (0, MyErr::FailOne)
}

fn returns_result() -> Result<u8, MyErr> {
    // Ok(1) // <-- Success path
    Err(MyErr::FailOne)
}

#[test]
fn test_check_return_values() {
    let x = returns_result();
    if x.is_ok() {
        println!("result: Is OK: {}", x.unwrap()); // <-- Must use unwrap
    } else {
        match x.err().unwrap() { // <-- Again, unwrapping
            MyErr::None => {}, // Required for match
            MyErr::FailOne => println!("result: Failed One"),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_check_return_values_2() {
    let (y, err) = returns_tuple();
    match err {
        MyErr::None => println!("tuple: Is OK: {}", y),
        MyErr::FailOne => println!("tuple: Failed one"),
    }
}
```

The only thing I can see is that it minorly increases the convenience of function writers, as you can simply call `Ok()` and `Err()` to return results.

I've seen some people saying its so you can use conditions, but that's not true at all; you can use conditions perfectly well using tuples. (*Note — "conditions" were a feature of Rust that were removed before 1.0*)

I've also seen some people saying that `Result` is more performant that returning a tuple, but `Result` *is* a tuple, so I don't see how this can be the case.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let's consider [the definition of `Result`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.5.0/src/libcore/result.rs#L241-L255):

```rust
/// `Result` is a type that represents either success (`Ok`) or failure
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Debug, Hash)]
#[must_use]
pub enum Result<T, E> {
    /// Contains the success value
    Ok(T),

    /// Contains the error value
    Err(E)
}
```

Distilled to the bits that matter, it's `enum Result<T, E> { Ok(T), Err(E) }`.

That is not a tuple `(T, E)`; rather, it is *either* a `T` (OK) *or* an `E` (error).

If you use a tuple `(T, E)`, you must define both the `T` *and* the `E`. For your `returns_tuple`, that meant defining 0 as a magic value and adding a new variant to your `MyErr` enumeration, `None`. `None` is not an error; it is semantically unsound to model it thus. It also then propagates to other places because of the requirement of exhaustive matching.

When you are dealing with more complex types, defining a dummy value may be less feasible or more expensive. As a generalisation, having dummy values is not a good plan. It's far too likely that somewhere down the track you will actually try to *use* them.

Rust has a good type system which allows you to avoid these sorts of problems.

It looks to me like you've missed the power of Rust's matching; in fact, the only way to get a value out of an enum is pattern matching; in consequence, things like `Result.ok()`, `Result.err()` and `Option.unwrap()` are implemented in terms of pattern matching.

Now let's write your example in a way that shows Rust in a better light.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MyErr {
    // Now we don't need that phoney None variant.
    FailOne,
}

fn returns_result() -> Result<u8, MyErr> {
    Err(MyErr::FailOne)
}

#[test]
fn test_check_return_values() {
    match returns_result() {
        Ok(num) => println!("result: Is OK: {}", num),
        Err(MyErr::FailOne) => println!("result: Failed One"),
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm late here, but I think you skimmed a really important point; `Result` serves as documentation by naming its potential values. This may seem small, but the reality is, when you're writing a lot of code, you need to look at the docs for functions that return `(a, b)` to know what's going on for certain; who knows if they're returning 1 or 0 on success, or if it's an error value at all? If I call a function expecting a `Foo` and I get `Result<Foo, _>`, I know for sure it's handling a potential error, and I know without question which return values are success values (those wrapped in `Ok`).

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is used to represent a nullable value, there could be some value or not, basically it wraps a nullable value and forces you to check for possible null case every time you want to access it.

`Result` is used to represent the result of a fallible operation, e.g IO operations or network requests, since there is possibility of a failure, type system forces you to check for possible error case every time you want to access the result data.