# Is it possible to cast type `std::result::Result` to `minhook::Hook`?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to cast type `std::result::Result` to `minhook::Hook` using [the minhook library](https://github.com/Jascha-N/minhook-rs)?

```
test =
    unsafe {
        minhook::Hook::<fn(f32, *mut UserCmd) -> bool>::create::<fn(f32, *mut UserCmd) -> bool>(hook_createmove, fn_ptrs.addy)
    } as minhook::Hook<fn(f32, *mut UserCmd) -> bool>;
```

`minhook::Hook:::create` returns a `std:::result::Result<Hook>`

As you can see, this is giving me the non-scalar cast problem. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Any case of "casting type `Result` into X" sounds horrible. Can you show a concrete example?

Comment: With that update, I can tell you that you just want proper error handling. That is covered in the book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).

Comment: So, I'm trying to make it so I can call test.enable, which is a `minhook::Hook` method. And I don't know how to achieve this. I need to call create and enable. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Alright @E_net4 thanks!!!

Comment: Your code is not really readable. You can use a type binding, like: `type MyFunc = fn(f32, *mut UserCmd) -> bool`

Comment: Hmmm.... good idea Boiethios I never thought of this, @E_net4 can you please answer it? So I can accept it as best answer?

Comment: I've answered it, although, as you might have realised, the question's quality is a bit on the poor side. We expect questions to show effort before being asked, and the subject of error handling with a result should be a fairly trivial one to grasp by either reading the book or checking the official documentation on the `Result` data type. It would have been a better question if it was narrowed down to a particular use of `Result` that you did not understand.

Comment: *As you can see* — no, we **cannot** because you haven't provided the complete error message! The library doesn't seem to have been published to crates.io yet, you didn't provide a link to the crate, and the crate I found with a matching name only compiles on certain platforms. This question provides very little information. Please review what a [MCVE] is and how to provide one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) is the standard type for representing success or failure of an operation in Rust. It's declared roughly like this:

```
enum Result<T, E> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
}
```

Any function that could fail in a fairly recoverable way (examples: attempting to open a file that does not exist or a parsing error occurred when reading a corrupted JSON file) will usually return a `Result`. See also [What's the benefit of using a Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187926/whats-the-benefit-of-using-a-result?rq=1).

You should **not** attempt to reinterpret result objects. Casting is not possible, and you should definitely not use transmutation. Instead, you should always (and I do mean always) use proper methods for handling them. Pointing out *just a few examples* of result handling:

- To assertively retrieve the positive outcome (the object of type `T`), use the [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) method. The program will panic if the result holds an error. This is often used when you are sure that no errors can happen in that particular case, or when you really want the program to terminate when that happens.
- In some other cases, you want to propagate an error out of a function. This is most elegantly achieved with the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-).

The Rust Programming language provides a comprehensive section on [Error Handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-00-error-handling.html), and Rust developers are strongly encouraged to understand these concepts.