# Why doesn't this rppal I2c struct have any methods?

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm been playing around with Rust on the raspberry pi, looking to build a coffee machine controller. I'm hit this problem super early on.
I'm using the rppal library with the hope of creating a i2c driver for a LCD screen.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `set_timeout` found for type `std::result::Result<rppal::i2c::I2c, rppal::i2c::Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:6
  |
8 |     foo.set_timeout(1000);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `set_slave_address` found for type `std::result::Result<rppal::i2c::I2c, rppal::i2c::Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 |     foo.set_slave_address(ADDR);
  |         ^^^^^^
```

I'm basicly following examples but it seems that I can't create a strut with the required methods!, feel like I'm missing something simple!

Here is the code, not a lot to it.

```rust
use rppal::i2c::I2c;

const ADDR: u16 = 0x27;

fn main() {
    println!("hello world");
    let mut foo = I2c::new();
    foo.set_timeout(1000);
    foo.set_slave_address(ADDR);
}
```

this is the library -> https://github.com/golemparts/rppal
and the example I was trying to copy -> https://github.com/golemparts/rppal/blob/master/examples/i2c_ds3231.rs

Many thanks!!

Comment: `I2c::new()` returns result not the instance that you expected you may use `except("...")` for quick solution  like : `I2c::new().except("Couldn't initiate")`  or you may want to understand what is `Result` type in Rust or  what is the use of `?` operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cast type \`std::result::Result\` to \`minhook::Hook\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756215/is-it-possible-to-cast-type-stdresultresult-to-minhookhook)

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yes that was the issue, I had taken out the `?` as it was creating other bug. Need to bit the bullet and stick my nose into the book for a week :).

Answer (score 0):

In the example you post there is this line:

```
let mut i2c = I2c::new()?;
```

The question mark is not an accident.  Note that in the error you get the type of i2c in your code:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `set_timeout` found for type `std::result::Result<rppal::i2c::I2c, rppal::i2c::Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:6
  |
8 |     foo.set_timeout(1000);
  |
```

It is not an `i2c`, but a `Result<i2c, Error>`.  The question mark in this case unpacks the `Result`, and if it is an error escalates it out of the current function.

Note that for this to work, your current function must also return a Result type, so you should match the `main()` function signiature given in the example to `fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>`

Comment: Yeah that was it, should do more research before continuing!

Comment: Rust, more than any language I have ever used, gives extremely helpful error messages.  Pay attention to them!