# How do I implement From to convert one Result type to another?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Is it possible to have a generic conversion of `Result<T, ErrorType1>` to `Result<T, ErrorType2>`, if `ErrorType2::From(ErrorType1)` is already implemented?  It seems like it should be possible.

This is my first attempt, but it doesn't compile.

```
impl<T> From<Result<T, LocalErrorType>> for Result<T, ForeignErrorType> {
    fn from<T>(res: Result<T, LocalErrorType>) -> Self {
        match sr {
            Ok(o) => Ok(o),
            Err(se) => Err(se.into())
        }
    }
}
```

because:

- `From` is a foreign trait
- `Result<T, LocalErrorType>` is a foreign type, despite `LocalErrorType` being a local type
- `Result<T, ForeignErrorType>` is also a foreign type

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not implement conversions between two `Result` types. Such a conversion is not needed for two reasons:

1. It is common and idiomatic to implement conversions *between error types* instead, from a specific type to a more generic error type. If none of the two types are more generic than the other one, one can create a new type that is the sum of both (i.e. an enum where each variant contains a distinct error type). With that, converting the result is as simple as using `map_err`:

   ```rust
   let res: Result<_, LocalErrorType> = do_something();
   let res: Result<_, GenericErrorType> = res.map_err(From::from);
   ```
2. You might not need to call `map_err` either, because the `?` operator (or the `try!` macro before 1.13) already converts the error type using a similar procedure underneath.

   ```rust
   fn do_something() -> Result<Foo, LocalErrorType> { unimplemented!() }

   fn foo() -> Result<(), GenericErrorType> {
       let stuff = do_something()?;
       Ok(())
   }
   ```

See also:

- [What's the benefit of using a Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187926/whats-the-benefit-of-using-a-result)
- [Is it possible to cast type `std::result::Result` to `minhook::Hook`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44756215/1233251)
- [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423)