# How to use a socket contained in the Result type in a chain of futures?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I have the following working code from the Tokio docs which I modified slightly:

```
// Task
let connection = io::read_exact(socket, buf_read)
    .and_then(|(socket, buf_read)| {
        println!("Do something with the received data...");
        for b in &buf_read {
            println!("{}", b);
        }

        // Write to the socket
        let buf_write = vec![19; 30];
        io::write_all(socket, buf_write)
    })
    .then(|res| {
        println!("{:?}", res); // Just for testing
        //Output: Ok((TcpStream, [19, 19, 19, ...]

        println!("Send data...");
        let buf_write = vec![18; 10]; // Fill the buffer with some data
        //
        //How to use the socket contained in res to write the data to the socket
        //    
        Ok(())
    });
```

In [the docs it is mentioned](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/)

> Note that `res` is a `Result` that contains the original socket. This allows us to sequence additional reads or writes on the same socket.

How to use the socket contained in the `Result` to write data to the socket?

Comment: You may be interested in using [`split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/*/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html#method.split) as well.

Comment: Can you explain how to use split here? As you can see from my code println!("{:?}", res) returns Ok((TcpStream, [19, 19, 19, ...].

How can I access the contained TcpStream and write data to the socket?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please start by re-reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition), specifically the chapter on [Recoverable Errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html). Then re-read the documentation for [the library you are using](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/).

[`Future::then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.then), emphasis mine:

> ```
> fn then<F, B>(self, f: F) -> Then<Self, B, F>
> where
>     F: FnOnce(Result<Self::Item, Self::Error>) -> B,
>     B: IntoFuture,
>     Self: Sized,
> ```
>
> Chain on a computation for when a future finished, passing the result
>   of the future to the provided closure `f`.
>
> This function can be used to ensure a computation runs **regardless of
>   the conclusion** of the future. The closure provided will be **yielded a
>   `Result`** once the future is complete.

Contrast this to the *other* function you are using, [`Future::and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then), emphasis mine:

> ```
> fn and_then<F, B>(self, f: F) -> AndThen<Self, B, F>
> where
>     F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> B,
>     B: IntoFuture<Error = Self::Error>,
>     Self: Sized,
> ```
>
> Execute another future after this one has resolved **successfully**.
>
> This function can be used to chain two futures together and ensure
>   that the final future isn't resolved until both have finished. The
>   closure provided is yielded **the successful result of this future** and
>   returns another value which can be converted into a future.

---

One solution is to only process it on success via `and_then`:

```
extern crate tokio; // 0.1.7

use tokio::{io, net::TcpStream, prelude::*};

fn example(socket: TcpStream, buf_read: Vec<u8>) {
    io::read_exact(socket, buf_read)
        .and_then(|(socket, buf_read)| {
            let buf_write = vec![19; 30];
            io::write_all(socket, buf_write)
        }).and_then(|(socket, data)| {
            let buf_write = vec![18; 10];
            io::write_all(socket, buf_write)
        });
    // TODO: use future somehow 
}
```

If you want to know about the failure, then you can continue to use `then` but you will have to handle the error somehow:

```
fn example(socket: TcpStream, buf_read: Vec<u8>) {
    io::read_exact(socket, buf_read)
        .and_then(|(socket, buf_read)| {
            let buf_write = vec![19; 30];
            io::write_all(socket, buf_write)
        }).then(|res| match res {
            Ok((socket, data)) => {
                let buf_write = vec![18; 10];
                io::write_all(socket, buf_write)
            }
            Err(e) => {
                // Do something with the error and return another
                // future that's type-compatible
                unimplemented!()
            },
        });
    // TODO: use future somehow
}
```

See also:

- [What's the benefit of using a Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22187926/155423)