# Rust how do I get to the inner nested structs parsed out of a config file in Rust config crate

Tags: rust

So I'm new to Rust and tinkering with some code to read a config file with nested values and while I seem to have the data, I'm just not sure how to get to the inner values.  Am I returning it wrong or is there some simple way to access this struct I'm missing?

This compiles and shows the values properly nested, but I don't seem to be able to reach inside the Ok() wrapper.  Even just a page number I should be reading in "The Book" would help.

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
dirs = "2.0"
config = "0.10"
serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
```

main.rs

```
extern crate dirs;
extern crate config;
extern crate serde;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use config::{ConfigError, Config, File};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct N4_env_conf {
    debug: bool,
    thingy: String,
    blue: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct N4_conf {
    local: N4_env_conf,
    dev: N4_env_conf,
    prod: N4_env_conf,
}

impl N4_conf {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Self, ConfigError> {
        let mut s = Config::new();

        s.merge(File::with_name("Settings"))?;
        s.try_into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let config_dir = format!("{}/.config/n4_config", dirs::home_dir().unwrap().display().to_string());
    let settings = N4_conf::new();

    println!("{:?}", config_dir);
    println!("{:#?}", settings);
}
```

Settings.toml

```
[local]
debug = true
thingy = "somethingy"
blue = "greenish"
[dev]
debug = true
thingy = "something"
blue = "green"
[prod]
debug = false
thingy = "otherthing"
blue = "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `settings` has the type `Result<N4_conf, ConfigError>`. That variable may contain a **value** of type `N4_conf` or an **error** of type `ConfigError`, dependent on the outcome of `N4_conf::new()`.

Example:

```
match settings {
    Ok(conf) => {
        println!("local = {:#?}", conf.local);
        assert_eq!(conf.local.debug, true);
        println!("local.debug = {:?}", conf.local.debug);
        println!("local.thingy = {:?}", conf.local.thingy);
        println!("local.blue = {:?}", conf.local.blue);

        println!("dev = {:#?}", conf.dev);
        println!("dev.debug = {:?}", conf.dev.debug);
        assert_eq!(conf.dev.debug, true);
        println!("dev.thingy = {:?}", conf.dev.thingy);
        println!("dev.blue = {:?}", conf.dev.blue);

        println!("prod = {:#?}", conf.prod);
        assert_eq!(conf.prod.debug, false);
        println!("prod.debug = {:?}", conf.prod.debug);
        println!("prod.thingy = {:?}", conf.prod.thingy);
        println!("prod.blue = {:?}", conf.prod.blue);
    }
    Err(e) => {
        panic!(e);
    }
}
```

See:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html
- [What's the benefit of using a Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187926/whats-the-benefit-of-using-a-result)

Answer (score 0):

So thank to @0x64 for trying to help you were definitely closer to the solution than I was when I posted this.  My issue was mainly just me trying to follow an example in the source repo for "config" too closely.  The solution was to handle the Result inside the constructor method and change the return type to Self.  My struct method changed to this and it behaves as I expected:

```
impl N4_conf {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Config::new();

        s.merge(File::with_name("Settings")).expect("Problem loading config file");
        match s.try_into() {
            Ok(conf) => {
                conf
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e);
                panic!(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it works, this performs perfectly returning a Struct I can access normally like so:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
Running `target/debug/config-playground`
"/home/kill-all-humans/.config/n4_config"
N4_conf {
    local: N4_env_conf {
        debug: true,
        thingy: "somethingy",
        blue: "greenish",
    },
    dev: N4_env_conf {
        debug: true,
        thingy: "something",
        blue: "green",
    },
    prod: N4_env_conf {
        debug: false,
        thingy: "otherthing",
        blue: "red",
    },
}
```

My next problem is this does not work at all consistently.  There appears to be an intermitten bug in processing hierarchical config files in the "config" crate.  Such that 50% of the time I get this instead, with zero code changes or rebuilds:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/config-playground`
missing field `local`
thread 'main' panicked at 'Box<Any>', src/main.rs:35:17
stack backtrace:
   0: backtrace::backtrace::libunwind::trace...
```

To which the "missing field" is literally whatever the first field in the N4_conf struct is.  I haven't dug into it deeply, but I think I'll skip this crate and just go back to dotenv.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `Config` module as I switched to `toml` for my main configuration files.  It does support all features from ini files and some more.  You might want to have a look.  Here is how [I use it](https://github.com/keltia/atlas-rs/blob/main/src/bin/atlas/config.rs)